# Undoing a function while requirements met

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is Take Food from  Variable "FGlasgow" and add it to Variable "Food", Nice and simple, But i noticed that even when FGlasgow became negative the script would still take more, So I told the script if Glasgow < 0 to add the food back and take a random number, The question is whether this can be shortened at all, and if my method is correct.

```
import random

def RandomNo():
    Random = random.randint(0,50)
    return Random

Food = 1
FGlasgow = 100


while True:
    Random = RandomNo()
    Food += Random
    FGlasgow -= Random
    while FGlasgow < 0:
        Food -= Random
        FGlasgow += Random
        Random = RandomNo()
        Food += Random
        FGlasgow -= Random
    print "You have found" , Random , "units of food"
```

Thank you for the help:) Any suggestions would be great:)

Comment: Check if `FGlasgow < Random` before you move the food. Better, choose `Random` to be between `1 and min(FGlasgow, 50)`

Comment: there's a typo in line 8 `FGlagow` should be `FGlasgow`

Comment: ...what's with the bizarre variable naming?

Comment: @sebastianmarkow Thanks i changed the Typo.

Comment: @nneonneo I have a lot of variables at the moment in my main script, so instead of writing FoodGlasgow, FoodEdinburgh so on so forth i decided to just make it FGlasgow and FEdinburgh.

Comment: @BlueLance: instead of having tons of oddly named global variables, try a *dictionary* instead.

Comment: Regarding variable naming, note [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FGlasgow` will become negative only if `Random` is greater than `FGlasgow`, so if you want to prevent that from happening just modify the arguments you use for `randint()` so that you can't get anything higher than `FGlasgow`:

```
import random

def RandomNo(upper=50):
    Random = random.randint(1, min(50, upper))
    return Random

Food = 1
FGlasgow = 100

while FGlasgow > 0:
    Random = RandomNo(FGlasgow)
    Food += Random
    FGlasgow -= Random
    print "You have found" , Random , "units of food"
```

Note that in both your code and mine eventually `FGlasgow` will reach 0, your code will be stuck in an infinte loop which is why I changed the `while` condition to eventually stop.

Comment: My original code (Not the one i posted) stops the infinite loop because my Random = randint(0,50) so it just runs until it gets a 0. not very efficient but im new to programming, but your code is far shorter and easier to understand:) plus it gives me a few things to look into and experiment with:) Thank you:).

Comment: Your code worked perfectly, I also managed to shrink it down by a line by just making it return the random.randint(1,min(50,upper)) function. If you know any tutorials that explain how to use the arguements properly id really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1):

You'll see I've changed the variable names. They have been changed according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

And as for your code, Yes it can be shortened. You don't need the outer while loop. Also, if you want to make sure that your `f_glasgow` doesn't go below 0, do this:

```
import random

def randomNo(limit):
    return random.randint(0,min(50,limit))

food = 1
f_glasgow = 100

while f_glasgow >= 0:
    x = randomNo(f_glasgow)
    food += x
    f_glasgow -= x
print "You have found" , food , "units of food"
```

Comment: +1 for making this look like Python and not VB/C#.

Comment: Thank you for the help:) Can you please point me in the right direction to find out what limit and min do or when it is suitable to use them? I'm new to all of this and I havn't found any tutorials that explain them.

Comment: Also i did try running it but it came up with an error sayingTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dante/Desktop/Shortening potential", line 10, in <module>
    x = randomNo()
TypeError: randomNo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @BlueLance Sorry, i forgot to give `f_glasgow` as an argument to the call Also, keep the limit as `f_glasgow`, and `min` is a built-in function, so it returns the smaller number of the 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just skip the first while loop? Also, I'm confused why you're doing the second random calculation. Couldn't that potentially negate the first one? Why not simply do:

```
def RandomNo():
    Random = random.randint(0,FGlasgow)
    return Random

if (FGlasgow > 0):
    Random = RandomNo()
    Food += Random
    FGlasgow -= Random
```

Comment: Sorry I had some typos regarding subtraction b/c I copy/pasted your code. The updated code will only run while FGlasgow is a positive number, so the problem if it being negative and continuing the calculation will never occur.

Comment: Oh I see, you are checking to see if Random was too big a number. You should edit your post to say that. Why not just put a limit on random? Set the range like Random = random.randint(1,FGlasgow) so it never generates a number bigger than FGlasgow.

Comment: See my edited post, Random will never be bigger than FGlasgow, and neither Food nor FGlasgow will ever be a negative number.

Comment: Had to delete some comments so it didnt give me a warning for extended discussions, The script runs infinitely so Food instantly becomes 101 i changed it to if and it works as it was intended:) Thanks

Comment: That works! You should probably define these as methods too, I'm not sure how the code is being used or called, but it's likely good to use class and method definitions.

Comment: At the moment they are in no classes, Im learning classes so at the moment its all just sorta thrown out there and being cleaned up every time I learn something new. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Gotcha, best of luck! Not a problem, if you feel like I answered your question adequately please mark it as answer (check mark button next to upvote/downvote) so other people with the same problems can see it.

Comment: Your answer is really really good, but schoolboys answer is more flexible for other needs as well as just mine, but thank you:)